# Why application is falling

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm try to changed colors of appbar and container in the random way, using provider. But, as always, all go wrong( Where did i make a mistake?
I've read some topics  on this thema, but don't understand, how does it work

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'dart:math';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class SwitchProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool is_switched = false;

  bool _switch() {
    is_switched = !is_switched;
    notifyListeners();
    return is_switched;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  bool is_changed = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SwitchProvider _state = Provider.of<SwitchProvider>(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider<SwitchProvider>.value(
        value: SwitchProvider(),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              "Homework Provider",
            ),
            backgroundColor: Color(
              generateRandomHexColor(),
            ),
          ),
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Color(
                  generateRandomHexColor(),
                ),
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
              ),
              Consumer(
                builder: (context, value, child) => Switch(
                  value: is_changed,
                  onChanged: (is_changed) => _state.is_switched,
                  // onChanged: (bool is_changed) => !is_changed,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Random random = new Random();

int generateRandomHexColor() {
  int length = 6;
  String chars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  String hex = '';
  while (length-- > 0) hex += chars[(random.nextInt(16)) | 0];
  print(hex);
  return int.parse("0xFF" + hex);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the error you got ?

Comment: It falls because Newton invented gravity.

Comment: If the question was edited, why not edit the the title as well? (and put a question mark at the end.) @NoahLewis is correct. The only logical answer to questions about why something is falling is due to gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to firstly initialize your provider and then you can access the provider. So you need to wrap your scaffold into another widget. So that you can access the provider after initializing the provider in material app widget. The code below should work.

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'dart:math';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class SwitchProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool is_switched = false;

  bool _switch() {
    is_switched = !is_switched;
    notifyListeners();
    return is_switched;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: ChangeNotifierProvider<SwitchProvider>.value(
        value: SwitchProvider(),
        child: Example()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final SwitchProvider _state = Provider.of<SwitchProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              "Homework Provider",
            ),
            backgroundColor: Color(
              generateRandomHexColor(),
            ),
          ),
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Color(
                  generateRandomHexColor(),
                ),
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
              ),
              Consumer(
                builder: (context, value, child) => Switch(
                  value: _state.is_switched,
                  onChanged: (_) => _state._switch(),
                  // onChanged: (bool is_changed) => !is_changed,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
  }
}

Random random = new Random();
int generateRandomHexColor() {
  int length = 6;
  String chars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  String hex = '';
  while (length-- > 0) hex += chars[(random.nextInt(16)) | 0];
  print(hex);
  return int.parse("0xFF" + hex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I understande the pricipal mechcanism by your example!

Answer (score 0):

try adding a timer with a periodic duration of 1 second then cancel the timer after 10 iterations.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

class ColorMonitor with ChangeNotifier
{
  Color shadowColor=Colors.red;
  Random random = new Random();
  Timer ?_timer;
  int counter=1;
  ColorMonitor()
  {
    startShadowColor();
  }
  startShadowColor(){
    _timer=Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1),switchColors);
  }
  switchColors(Timer timer)  {
    
    shadowColor=Color(generateRandomHexColor());
    if (counter>=10){
      timer.cancel();
    }
    else{
      counter+=1;
      notifyListeners();
      }
    
  }
  int generateRandomHexColor() {
    int length = 6;
    String chars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    String hex = '';
    while (length-- > 0) hex += chars[(random.nextInt(16)) | 0];
    //print(hex);
    return int.parse("0xFF" + hex);
  }
}
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home:  
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ColorMonitor>.value(
        value:ColorMonitor(),
        child:
      TestAppBar()),
    );
  }
}

class TestAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  TestAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestAppBar> createState() => _TestAppBarState();
}

class _TestAppBarState extends State<TestAppBar> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }
  
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    //Provider.of<ColorMonitor>(context,listen:true).startShadowColor();
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return 
    
    Scaffold(appBar:
    AppBar(title:Text("App Bar Color Change"),backgroundColor:Provider.of<ColorMonitor>(context,listen:true).shadowColor),
    body:
    Center(child:
    Text(Provider.of<ColorMonitor>(context,listen:true).counter.toString(),style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayLarge)
    ));
  }
}
```